# Database First with Bridge Table, How to Keep It Out of Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am trying to find out how I can make a bridge table entity, used for a many to many relationship, transparent to my model.  I am using EF **Database First**.

**Tables in question**...(simplified)

```
Report
- ReportId INT PK
- ReportName VARCHAR(50)

Group
- GroupId INT PK
- GroupName VARCHAR(50)

ReportGroup
 - ReportId INT PK
 - GroupId INT PK
```

**Current Class Structure**...(simplified)

```
public class Report
{
     public int ReportId { get; set; }
     public string ReportName { get; set; }
     public IList<ReportGroup> ReportGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
     public int GroupId { get; set; }
     public string GroupName { get; set; }
     public IList<ReportGroup> ReportGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ReportGroup
{
     public int ReportId { get; set; }
     public Report Report { get; set; }
     public int GroupId { get; set; }
     public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Using the above, to get the groups that a Report belongs to requires something like this...

```
// Getting a report's groups
var report = this.ReportService.GetReportById(123456);
var groups = report.ReportGroups.Select(x => x.Group).ToList();
```

That's not exactly something I want to be using throughout my application.  Ideally, I'd like the bridge table and Entity (ReportGroup) to be transparent, allowing me to work with the entities like this...

```
// Getting a report's groups
var report = this.ReportService.GetReportById(123456);
var groups = report.Groups;

// Getting a group's reports
var group = this.ReportService.GetGroupById(1);
var reports = group.Reports;
```

So my question is whether this is possible with EF **Database First**, and if so, how do I wire this up correctly using the Fluent API in **OnModelCreating**().

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Who made the "current class structure"? The "Create model from database wizard"?

Comment: Negative...hand coded classes.  Very small model.

Comment: Hm, why do you call it *Database First* then? Hand coded classes sounds more like *Code-First*. Anyway, you already have a solution below...

Comment: It's database first because the database already existed.  I didn't hand code classes and then generate the database from the model...that would be code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You if use ReportGroup just for relations you don't need this POCO class just map it OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
...
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GroupMap());
...
}

public class GroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
    {
        public GroupMap()
        {
            // Relationships
            this.HasMany(e => e.Reports)
              .WithMany(set => set.Groups)
              .Map(mc =>
              {
                  mc.ToTable("groupreporttablename");
                  mc.MapLeftKey("GroupID");
                  mc.MapRightKey("ReportID");
              });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using the above approach, what is the best way add Reports to Groups when the ReportGroup entity is not exposed to the model?  I see that I can use existing instances of Group, but I'd like to avoid having to pull down instances just for association.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you competly. You can: report.Groups.Add(...), group.Reports.Add(...), if you prefere to full control ReportGroup table just map it and you will have opportunity to add reportgroups to report and group entity.

Comment: @ctorx: You can create attached stub objects to create associations between existing objects without loading objects from the DB: `var group = new Group { Id = 5 }; context.Groups.Attach(group); report.Groups.Add(group);` (`report` must be attached as well).

Comment: OK, got it.  It's an extra step then...for example, when I had the ReportGroup entity, I could add to it without interacting with the Context and the new records would be persisted.  Since I've removed it from my model, it sounds like I need to do adds via the context.  Thx.