# EF 4.3 Many to Many Relation and Junction Table Update

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

```
public class User
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAction> UserActions{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAction> UserActions{ get; set; }
}

public UserAction
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public User User{ get; set; }
    public Action Action{ get; set; }
    public int Type {get;set}       
}
```

and in repository class

```
public void Update(User user,List<UserAction> actions)
{
    User entity = this.GetUser(user.Id);           
    entity.UserActions.Clear();
    entity.UserActions= actions;
    this.siteRepository.Update<SiteUser>(user);
    this.siteRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

i am gettng a error below like

The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What is it that Update should do? Do the UserAction instances you pass in already have Users and Actions associated with them that you want to change? Can you explain what you want to do rather than just posting code?

Comment: do u know many to many relation at EF?its that.

Comment: What you have in your example is not what EF considers a many-to-many relationship since you have mapped the join table. Mapping the join table is fine. But what do you want to do?

Comment: Mapping is fine but,i didnt delete junction table data,normaly if there isnt a Type property  in junction table,its easy.

Comment: The exception you are getting indicates that you have an FK mapped to some property. I don't see an FK mapped in any of the code you posted. Could you update with the code that contains the FK property or point out in your code which property you have mapped to an FK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need semething like this if you want to replace the existing `UserActions` collection in the database by the new collection you are passing into the method. Especially it is necessary that you delete the `UserActions` which have been removed from the collection also from the database because apparently the relationship is required and the user actions either must refer to a user entity or they must be deleted (that's what the exception says):

```
User entity = context.Users.Include(u => u.UserActions)
    .Single(u => u.Id == user.Id);

context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);
foreach (var userAction in entity.UserActions.ToList())
    if (!user.UserActions.Any(ua => ua.Id == userAction.Id))
        context.UserActions.Remove(userAction);   // DELETE is important here!

foreach (var userAction in user.UserActions)
{
    var userActioninDB = entity.UserActions
        .SingleOrDefault(ua => ua.Id == userAction.Id);
    if (userActionInDB == null)
        entity.UserActions.Add(userActioninDB);
    else
        context.Entry(userActioninDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(userAction);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

You must translate this into your repository structure.

Comment: Shouldn't the line where you Add the UserActions row be `entity.UserActions.Add(userAction)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Slauma,Solution is

```
List<UserAction> actions = new List<UserAction>(user.UserActions.ToList());

foreach (var action in actions )
{
  Delete<UserAction>(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Users collection to Action class and Actions to User. You even can not map UserAction table if user and action in pair are unique for this table.

I answered quite the same here:
[Database First with Bridge Table, How to Keep It Out of Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745057/database-first-with-bridge-table-how-to-keep-it-out-of-model/9745236#9745236)

Comment: yes,iknow but my bridge table has a field,its called by Type , i dont hide that UserAction

Comment: So just add entities using UserAction it's the only way. Surely u can use action or user entities methos add but anyway first you must create UserAction enetity

Comment: no its not possible this scenerio,i must use Type property in junction table.